# Jquery .get function returns [Object object]

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
function getsession(){
    var data = $.get('../session', function(data)
    {
        return data;
    });
    return data;
}


alert(getsession());
```

returns `[object Object]`

I want it to return the data from the GET.

Comment: The other duplicate: [Javascript - \[object Object\] means?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8892465/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
function getAndProccessSession(){
    $.get('../session', function(returnedSessionData)
    {
        console.log(returnedSessionData);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function passed `$.get` is executed asynchronously after the HTTP request is finished, you can't get a return variable.

After `$("#openSession").append(data)`, you could also `alert(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the data and your using firefox maybe some others you can use

```
alert(getsession().toSource());
```

that way you can see the object that your getting back but if you know the data items you can target them direct

```
 alert(getsession().someItemInTheObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google chrome you can do a console.log(getsession()) within your code and then press ctr+shift+c to open google chrome dev tools, then go to the console tab, you can see the object there and you can click it to view its internal properties values